# GeoExt 2 - Extjs 4

Tags: geoext, ext-js

As a complement to my previous post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309998/extjs-4-with-geoext-libraries-issue

i can't find a css file for GeoExt 2 here : https://github.com/geoext/geoext2

i just could've find GeoExt javascript in src folder

i really need to use GeoExt 2 so anyone can find me a good source ?

Answer (score 2):

It has been long time after question but;

You don't need a CSS file for GeoExt2. It is enough to show GeoExt2-loader.js directory in your index.html file. For example my app like this

```
<html>
   <head>

    <title>MY APP</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext41/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext41/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext41/locale/ext-lang-tr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ol/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GeoExt2/.../loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
    <!-- other js files -->

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally you can need to modify your loader.js file to show Ext JS 4 and GeoExt2 directory.

**AN IMPORTANT NOTE: GeoExt2 works with only ExtJS 4.1.x and 4.0.x not ExtJS 4.2.x**